# Doing SSH via PERL

Tags: regex, perl, ssh

I want to login to a different shell in a different server. So i wrote the following code.

```
#!/volume/perl/bin/perl
use lib qw(/volume/labtools/lib);
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = 'wd-shell2';
my $cmd = "cd /volume/ftp/private/det/os;ls -lrt jinstall*";
my $user = 'joydeep';
my $pass = '';
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$host", debug=>0);
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd);
print "\n$stdout\n";
```

**I am not sure, whether i wrote it right or not. i am in tts-shell1, how can i login to wd-shell2 and do my thing with the code(after correcting). Please help me here.**

Answer (score 1):

First off, always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.

Secondly, you should turn on `debug` mode so the module will give you as many helpful messages as possible:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$host", debug => 1);
```